# Reverse row and colums in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tryng to reverse this but I can't figure out how.
I'm starting from

```
>>> d = {'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     3
3    B     4
4    B     5
5    B     6
6    C     7
7    C     7
```

And I want to obtain:

```
col1  new_1  new_2  new_3
0    A      1      2      3
1    B      4      5      6
2    C      7      7  empty
```

where there are new_x columns based on max number of times a col1 item is repeated.
It seems to be a pretty standard transpose, but I can't find a solution.

Sorry if duplicated.

Thx
Sirius

Comment: Does `empty` mean no value, or the `'empty'` string? :-)

Answer (score 3):

use `.cumcount()` and `.unstack()` after setting your indices.

`cumcount()` here groups by your target column and applies a sequential count along the index, this allows us to `unstack()` it and create your new pivoted structure.

the rest of the code is to obtain your target dataframe, you could also do this with pivot and crosstab.

```
df1 = df.set_index([df.groupby('col1').cumcount() + 1,
                    df['col1']]).drop('col1',1)\
                    .unstack(0)\
                    .droplevel(0,1)\
                    .add_prefix('new_')\
                    .fillna('empty')\
                    .reset_index()
```

Or with pivot:

```
(df.assign(k=df.groupby("col1").cumcount()+1).pivot('col1','k','col2')
   .add_prefix("col_").reset_index())
```

---

```
  col1  new_1  new_2  new_3
0    A    1.0    2.0    3.0
1    B    4.0    5.0    6.0
2    C    7.0    7.0  empty
```

Comment: @anky you are always free to edit my answers my friend :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a one-liner but maybe a bit simpler / easier to follow.

First, aggregate to one lists column:

```py
df_ = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('col1').col2.agg(list))
```

which gives

```
           col2
col1           
A     [1, 2, 3]
B     [4, 5, 6]
C        [7, 7]
```

Then, build a new DataFrame from these lists:

```py
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df_.col2.tolist(), index=df_.index).add_prefix('new_')
                                                       .reset_index())
```

which gives

```
  col1  new_0  new_1  new_2
0    A      1      2    3.0
1    B      4      5    6.0
2    C      7      7    NaN
```

Please note that:

- I interpreted `empty` as an empty cell, not the `'empty'` string
- `NaN` is always seen as a float, that's why values in this column were cast by pandas to floats

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = {'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 print(df)
 print(df.pivot_table(index='col1',columns=df.index, values='col2').fillna(0))
```

output:

```
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
  col1                                        
  A     1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
  B     0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  0.0  0.0
  C     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0  7.0
```